# how to append input fields to a div without clearing the values with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that appends a div that contains input fields and textareas to a parent div on click of a button. when I append the div and input some values in the fields and then append a new div, the values of the input fields somehow becomes empty. how can it fix this problem?

here is the code:

```
let counter = 1;
let new_section = document.getElementsByClassName("addnew")[0];
document.getElementById("shownew").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  new_section.innerHTML += `   <div class="lowerlayer2">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Word Type" id="wtype${counter}" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Synonym" id="syn${counter}" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Antonyms" id="anty${counter}" />

  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="History & Etymology"
    id="history${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="Examples"
    id="example${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="Definition 1"
    id="def1${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  </div>`;

  counter++;
});
```

Comment: `innerHTML+=...` re-sets the value with a new string so all the contents of the element get removed, the the new html string is parsed and new elements made. If you want to add elements without destroying/recreating previous content use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) or [`insertAdjacentElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Using `new_section.innerHTML` you are not appending, but overwriting the content of this `new_section`. Try reading up on [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://javascript.info/modifying-document#insertadjacenthtml-text-element)

Comment: thanks `insertAdjacentHtml()` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal example using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://javascript.info/modifying-document#insertadjacenthtml-text-element):

```js
let addedCounter = 1;
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "add") {
    return addStuff();
  }
}

function addStuff() {
  document.querySelector("#container")
    .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
      <p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Word Type" id="wtype${addedCounter}" />
      </p>`);
    addedCounter += 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="add">Add stuff</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML += overwrites the entire HTML instead of simply adding to it. Values are not included in the overwrite.

appendChild() will add to the div as expected if you don't mind it inserting an additional node. In your case you are adding a div anyways so its ok.

```
var newInfo = document.createElement('div'); // this makes a node, a node is require for appendChild. You could also use 'p' or 'span' etc.
newInfo.setAttribute("class", "lowerlayer2"); // you can add your classes and id etc with setAttribute
newInfo.innerHTML = "data to be added/appended";
document.getElementById("newtestdiv").appendChild(newInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the input elements
let input_one = document.getElementById('INPUT_ONE_ID');
let input_two = document.getElementById('INPUT_TWO_ID');
let input_three = document.getElementById('INPUT_THREE_ID');
let counter = 1;
let new_section = document.getElementsByClassName("addnew")[0];
document.getElementById("shownew").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // instead of creating new elements, append the old input elements
  new_section.innerHTML += `   <div class="lowerlayer2">`+input_one+input_two+input_three+`

  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="History & Etymology"
    id="history${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="Examples"
    id="example${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  <textarea
    cols="30"
    rows="10"
    placeholder="Definition 1"
    id="def1${counter}"
  ></textarea>
  </div>`;

  counter++;
});
```